# Question about desicion symbol in flowchart

Tags: documentation, process, flowchart

I am trying to make a flowchart of my program (yes I know it is the wrong order to do it:) )
and I made a desicion symbol to represent the actionsheet I display in the iPhone application. It prompts the user "Yes, No, Cancel", so it is three options. However on all the templates/tutorials I have seen they only use "Yes" and "No" over the arrows which lead out from the desicion symbol. So could I use "Cancel" as well? If not how could I have done it otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do whatever you want with it, as long as it simplifies the meaning for your program. Decision making isn't restricted to 'yes' and 'no'.

Most of the time, flow charts are used to explain program logic to non-programmers. Your goal is to get them to understand what you program. We often use visual tools for this. You want to put all relevant information on there. If the cancel button is important to your program, put it on there. In my opinion there is no strict rule about what a flowchart should look like. Over time some basic form of flowchart has grown but you can add or remove whatever you want if it allows you to make more comprehensible charts.

Comment: Thank you. I just thought of something, is it normal to show such actions in flowcharts? I mean "Cancel" in my program just closes the actionsheet. Right now I have a arrow named cancel which just points back to the start point in the program.

Comment: If it is relevant to the program logic, keep it in. Nobody forces you to follow some sort of standard for making flowchart. If you find a way to express the logic in a more understandable manner, do it.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia suggests that decisions can have more than 2 choices, but should maybe be broken down.  I see two options using a Google Docs drawing:

https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/11AhEIUOr9SdhXB1REculUy0NF9c628qaxfYVacUGfzU/edit?hl=en_US

I agree with the previous answer that the simpler it looks the better... whatever makes it most understandable.  I think it's simpler to have 3 choices out of the 1 decision.

Comment: Thank you. I have an button in my test that might cause the test to be aborted, should this be included in the flowchart? Or should I just show the flow that the program would run in if it was succeeded?

Comment: I would guess it should be included.  A good indicator is probably if the code for branching to the abort situation is near the code for the other options.  If yes, then it is likely conceptually close to the rest of the decision and a significant piece of the decision process.